# AWS Linux Stuck due to screen command - blank screen - how to get out

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-web-services, gnu-screen, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS Linux (Amazon Linux 2 AMI) and I am totally stuck after using the basic "screen" command.

I was following an installation guide and one of the steps was to use just the command "screen" and hit enter.  I did that and got a blank screen.  The guide says to use ctrl-a+d, etc to get out.  Well, that didn't do anything.  So, after trying those keyboard commands with nothing happening, I just closed the terminal window and tried to connect again.

The issue now is that I get the startup splash screen where it says  EC2 Amazon Linux 2 AMI, but it is still a blank screen under that - no $ or user-name or anything like that. I can't figure out how to enter any commands on this screen.

I rebooted the instance.  stopped it, started it.  Nothing changes this screen.  I have other users built that aren't root users that still work, but my ec2-user (root) just goes to this blank screen every time.

Does anyone know how to kill this screen or get this to reset so I can login as ec2-user and actually do anything?  I have tried all the keyboard shortcuts. I can't figure out how to find and kill the screen using a non-root user and I can't do anything as my ec2-user (root).

Please, any advice is welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to press **`ctrl + a`** then press **`k`**. It will ask if you really want to kill the session press **`y`**